# Recover launch stages in KSP

Tags: kerbal-space-program

How can I recover the pre-orbital stages of a spaceship in Kerbal Space Program? I'm trying to reduce my per-launch costs in the beginning of career mode.

I tried building my spaceship with radial stages each topped with a [stayputnik](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Stayputnik_Mk._1) and a pair of [radial parachutes](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Mk2-R_Radial-Mount_Parachute). I set the parachutes to deploy at the same time as the [decouplers](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/TT-38K_Radial_Decoupler), and could see them deploy in the staging view during flight. I expected to see these pieces as either probes or debris in the [tracking station](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Tracking_Station), but they were never listed. The stacks are small enough (an [LV-T45](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/LV-T45_Liquid_Fuel_Engine) and about an [FL-T800](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/FL-T800_Fuel_Tank)s's worth of fuel) that 2 radial 'chutes should have been enough to bring them down safely. Is there a way to recover these pre-orbital stages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I get a refund for parts that land on rails?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178757/do-i-get-a-refund-for-parts-that-land-on-rails)

Comment: @Philipp Finding or asking the question you linked relies on having an intimate understanding of the internals of KSP. This question does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this is that any on-rails object below 25km in Kerbin's atmosphere will be deleted, as it is assumed it burnt up/impacted. In order to recover stages, you will need a mod. The two major mods for this are [StageRecovery](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/86677-0-90-StageRecovery-Recover-Funds-from-Dropped-Stages-v1-5-2-1-%2812-15-14%29) and [DebRefund](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/86691-0-24-2-DebRefund-v1-0-13). They both do the same thing, but StageRecovery has an in-game settings panel.